# Windows powershell command, use output from one command directly as parameter in another

Tags: powershell, kubectl

I would like to have a command that gets the name of a pod and then uses it to log in to the pod.
The command to list the pods to get the pod name:

```
kubectl get pods | Select-String -Pattern "mypodname"
```

The output is:

```
mypodname 1/1 Running    0  4d3h
```

I need to only get the value mypodname here. I have tried with Select-Object NAME with no luck. The podname changes over time. For example it can be mypodname-3467gogsfg one day
and mypodname-043086dndn the next day because of new deployment.

This value I will use in this command:

```
kubectl --server=https://myservername.com --insecure-skip-tls-verify exec -it <name of pod goes here> /bin/sh
```

The second question is how these two can be combined in a windows powershell script so
I can run something like this to log in to the pod:

```
podlogin mypodname
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function is probably what you're after since you're looking to combine the results into an execution by passing just the name:

```
Function PodLogin ($PodName) {
    $name = kubectl get pods | ? { $_ -match "(?<=($PodName-.*))\s" } | % { $Matches[1] }
    kubectl --server=https://myservername.com --insecure-skip-tls-verify exec -it $name /bin/sh
}
```

The use of `Where-Object` (`?`) just allows for a more condensed code without having to dig through the properties for the value matched since `-Match` will populate the  `$Matches` [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2). Then, piping to `Foreach-Object` (`%`) to access the value matched via `$Matches[1]`; *although not necessarily needed, saving it to a `$name` is more appealing overall*. Finally, pass the `$name` to your command for execution.

Now you can call it using `PodLogin podname`.

Here's a RegEx [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xI3oUK/1) that explains the pattern.

- Assuming the pattern is always `podname-....` , which is followed by a space.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you can split the output and then assign the first word to a variable.  The output of kubectl is text, not an object.

```
$podname = -split (kubectl get pods | select-string mypodname) | select -first 1
$podname

mypodname


podlogin $podname
```